# php get closest timestamp but less than current timestamp

Tags: php, arrays, date, timestamp

I'm working with timestamp in an array as value, for example :

- 1455874500 : 19/02/2016 09h35
- 1455879600 : 19/02/2016 11h00
- 1455921300 : 19/02/2016 22h35

And the thing I would like to do is to get the closest timestamp from my array BUT if this timestamp is higher than the current timestamp (closest > current timestamp), get the lower value.

Here is an example to illustrate my point, it's 19/02/2016 10h58, I don't want to get 1455879600 (19/02/2016 11h00) but 1455874500 (19/02/2016 09h35) AND then, when it is 19/02/2016 11h00, get 1455879600.

I've been working on this code :

```
function find_closest($id, $date_now){
    global $cnx;
    $sql = "select position_history from worksheets WHERE id = $id LIMIT 1";

    $stmt = $cnx->prepare($sql);
    try {
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    $pos_lane = unserialize($result->position_history);

    $i=0;

    $array = array();

    foreach ($pos_lane as $item) {
        // $exp[2] : timestamp
        $exp = explode("|", $pos_lane[$i]);
        $array[$exp[1]] = $exp[2];
        $i++;
    }

    $mostrecent = "0";
    foreach($array as $timestampmove)
    {
          if ($timestampmove > $mostrecent && $timestampmove < $date_now) {
             $mostrecent = $timestampmove;
          }
    }

    $closeto = array_search($mostrecent,$array);

    return $closeto;

}
```

which aim to select the most recent timestamp BEFORE today but it does not seem to work as I want...

Maybe you have a better solution for me?

thank you !

Comment: you mean something like [this](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5b589787f5723bf20ffb6c28879763425ba75fa1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following:

```
foreach ($pos_lane as $item) {
    // $exp[2] : timestamp
    $exp = explode("|", $pos_lane[$i]);
    $array[$exp[1]] = (int) $exp[2];   // <<< cast to int
    $i++;
}

$mostrecent = 0;
$closeto = null;
foreach($array as $key => $timestampmove)
{
    if ($timestampmove < $date_now) {  // <<< make sure $date_now is a Unix timestamp
        if ($mostrecent < $timestampmove) {
            $mostrecent = $timestampmove;
            $closeto = $key;
        }
    }
}

return $closeto;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it seems to work pretty well ! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Why not make it simpler and have the original sql query do the work for you?

```
 $sql = "select MAX(position_history) from worksheets WHERE id = $id and position_history < now() LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I forget to say that...
My timestamps, that are in position_history are serialized, that's why i'm doing an explode ("ORIGIN|DESTINATION|TIMESTAMP") to get my timestamp ($exp[2])... :(